# Accessing Linux Environment Variable from Java Program

Tags: java, linux, jdk1.4

I have Java Program which access the Linux Variable(example `$VARD`, i have exported the variable as well), I am accessing the variable value using `Runtime.getRuntime("echo $VARD")` function. Issue is it prints variable name instead of its value.

Note: I am running this program in Linux server where it has JAVA JDK 1.4 version. I knew we can do that using `getenv().get()` function which is available from JDK 1.5..

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610080/can-we-read-the-os-environment-variables-in-java

Comment: you might find what I want with System.getProperties() ?

Answer (score 1):

In general you should use `System.getProperty()` or `System.getEnv()`.

```
import java.lang.*;

public class SystemDemo {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

     // prints Java Runtime Version before property set
     System.out.print("Previous : ");
     System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.runtime.version" ));
     System.setProperty("java.runtime.version", "Java Runtime 1.6.0");

     // prints Java Runtime Version after property set
     System.out.print("New : ");
     System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.runtime.version" ));
   }
}
```

---

```
import java.util.Map;

public class EnvMap {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
            System.out.format("%s=%s%n",
                              envName,
                              env.get(envName));
        }
    }
}
```

If you are using maven there is another option. You can access environment variables from maven by using `${env.VARIABLE_NAME}`.

Comment: 1. Program is used to access the predefined property value