# Sending mail through java requires password which expires every month

Tags: java, jakarta-mail

I wrote a code that sends mail through javax.mail. But it requires authentication.And the password of the mail account needs to be changed every month.So if I hard code the password in code,I will have to manipulate the code every month. Is there any way to sort it out?

Any Help would be appreciated!!

Comment: You can use file or database to store password instead of hard coding it in code

Answer (score 0):

There is a number of solutions. The easiest ones are:

- either keep your password in [property file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8285595/reading-properties-file-in-java) (not secure enough unless you implement some encryption mechanisms)
- or propagate the password to your code as a [command line parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890966/what-is-string-args-parameter-in-main-method-java) or an [environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610080/can-we-read-the-os-environment-variables-in-java).