# How to get OS environment variable from Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, environment-variables

I am novice to java and spring framework. My questions is how to inject OS(ubuntu) environment variable to spring boot bean. What I tried:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {
 @Value("${COMPONENT_PARAM_CORS}")
 private String COMPONENT_PARAM_CORS;

 @Override
 public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
  registry.addMapping("/"+COMPONENT_PARAM_CORS);
 }
}
```

export COMPONENT_PARAM_CORS=**

printenv

says me that its present, but when I try to mvn clean install: error occured

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load ApplicationContext
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error 
creating bean with name 'corsConfig': Injection of autowired dependencies 
failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not 
resolve placeholder 'COMPONENT_PARAM_CORS' in value "${COMPONENT_PARAM_CORS}"
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Could not resolve placeholder 
'COMPONENT_PARAM_CORS' in value "${COMPONENT_PARAM_CORS}"
```

and then my unit test also droped
(I am trying to search this error, but all topics is old and uses params from application.properties, but I need to use env var not application.properties)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `System.getenv(<environment name>)` method to retrieve an environment variable value. Like:

```
registry.addMapping("/" + System.getenv("COMPONENT_PARAM_CORS"));
```

or with default value:

```
registry.addMapping("/" + System.getenv().getOrDefault("COMPONENT_PARAM_CORS", "DEFAULT_VALUE"))
```

More information here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html

If you really want to *inject* variable value you can modify your code to something like:

```
@Value("#{systemEnvironment['COMPONENT_PARAM_CORS'] ?: 'DEFAULT_VALUE'}")
private String COMPONENT_PARAM_CORS;
```

Comment: I know about `System.getenv()`, but it work when app is compiled, but I need to receive params when I run application, or `@value` also precompiled?

Comment: Both `System.getenv()` and SPEL expression within `@Value` will be executed at runtime, not compile time, so both options should work for you.

Comment: And I can use default value like :

Comment: For default value you can use argumentless `System.getenv()` call which gives you a `Map<String, String>`. Then call `getOrDefault(key, defaultValue)` method (java 1.8+).  And for SPEL option just use elvis operator: `?:`. I have adjusted my answer to show this.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [System.getenv()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html#getenv%28%29), for example:

```
import java.util.Map;

public class EnvMap {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        Map<String, String> env = System.getenv();
        for (String envName : env.keySet()) {
            System.out.format("%s=%s%n",
                              envName,
                              env.get(envName));
        }
    }
}
```

Please refer to [This documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/env.html) and [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20610080/can-we-read-the-os-environment-variables-in-java).

Answer (score 0):

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class CorsConfig implements WebMvcConfigurer {

 @Value("#{systemEnvironment['COMPONENT_PARAM_CORS']?:'**'}")
 private String COMPONENT_PARAM_CORS;

 @Override
 public void addCorsMappings(CorsRegistry registry) {
  registry.addMapping("/"+COMPONENT_PARAM_CORS);
 }
}
```